# Difference between "A <T>(IList<T> x) where T : I" and "A(IList<I> x)"?

Tags: c#, generics, methods, types, interface

What is the difference between

```
public void MyMethod<T>(IList<T> myParameter) where T : IMyInterface
```

and

```
public void MyMethod(IList<IMyInterface> myParameter)
```

?

Comment: One is generic and another is not :) but it is obviously not what you are asking - can you comment/accept D Stanley's answer so it is clear what you are looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`IList<T>` is not [covariant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx), so you could not pass an `IList<SomeObjectThatImplementsIMyInterface>` to the second method.

Suppose you could, and you had:

```
class MyClass1 : IMyInterface {}
class MyClass2 : IMyInterface {}
```

and the implementation of `MyMethod` was:

```
MyMethod(IList<IMyInterface> myParameter)
{
    // perfectly valid since myParameter can hold 
    // any type that implements IMyInterface
    myParameter.Add(new MyClass2());
}
```

if you tried to call

```
MyMethod(new List<MyClass1>()) ;
```

it would fail at runtime because the list is defined to contain `MyClass1` objects and cannot hold a `MyClass2` object.

Comment: Excellent answer. Nicely worded and laid out.